# DFA Automaton for all words that starts with 01 and ends with 01

Tags: formal-languages

$L=\left\{w \in\{0,1\}^{*} \mid \text { w starts with } 01 \text { and ends with } 01\right\}$

I need to draw a dfa and nfa , I managed to draw the nfa but the dfa didn't .. can someone lead me please?

Answer (score 0):

[image: DFA for w that starts and ends with 01]

Does the above DFA work? Start State is S, Accepting State is B, and T is a terminal state.

Comment: yes I think it works , I didn't know that "01" is also acceptable

Comment: Yes "01" is an acceptable word given the constraints in the question.

Comment: Minor correction: you may need a self-loop labeled '0' on C.

Comment: of course. Thank you